# Send location via sms Button doesn't work - android studio

Tags: java, android, button

I tried to send my location via SMS, but the button doesn't work.
The button was working fine before I added the code of getting current location.

Can you please help me to fix that? I tried many solutions that I found in this website, but it doesn't work with me.
I am totally new to Android Studio, so I don't know how to write my code that it will work the way I want it.

```
private LocationManager locationManager;
private LocationListener locationListener;

String[] appPermissions = {
        android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
        android.Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS
};
private static final int PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE = 123;

private static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_SEND_SMS = 0;
double x,y;

Button sendBtn;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (checkAndRequestPermissons()) {

    }
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    locationListener = new LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            x = location.getAltitude() ;
            y = location.getLongitude();
            Log.d("Location", location.toString());

        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

        }

    };

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);




    sendBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSendSMS);
    sendBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            sendSMSMessage();
        }
    });

}
protected void sendSMSMessage() {

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS)) {
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_SEND_SMS);
        }
    }
}
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_SEND_SMS: {
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                smsManager.sendTextMessage("+212xxxxx", null, "Je suis en danger, voici ma localisation : https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=" + x + "," + y , null, null);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "SMS sent.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "SMS faild, please try again.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;
            }
        }
    }

}
private boolean checkAndRequestPermissons() {
    List<String> listPermissionsNeeded = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String perm : appPermissions)
    {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,perm) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        {
            listPermissionsNeeded.add(perm);
        }
    }
    if (!listPermissionsNeeded.isEmpty())
    {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,listPermissionsNeeded.toArray(
                new String[listPermissionsNeeded.size()]),PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE
        );
        return  false;

    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: "the button deosn't work" -- what do you mean? What are your specific symptoms?

Comment: when i press the button nothing happen it doesn't work